# Security issue from php due to suspicious behaviour in my server from other country

Tags: php, security, server

I am developing a web application. We are about release my first application but i found some unexpected bahaviour on my server.

[image]

Could anyone tell me what he tried to do?
one of my colleague told me that we should not PHP anymore.

I am planning to change our framework to Laravel. but i am just afraid that if security is real issue then i am willing to move but the reason that my colleague is saying does not persuasive to me.

Comment: is it developed in Wordpress ?? i could see some wp-config.php files here..

Comment: We used codeigniter.

Comment: Just i am worried and curious that what this person tried to do..

Comment: obviously check index.php for any injected code, if your site still works your fine, it just looks like a scan

Comment: my colleague is keep insisting that i should not use php because of this. So i need a valid reason for my clients.

Comment: is it hosting server or personal VPS? if hosting which hosting provider ?

Comment: i am using AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does look like a scan by a bot to me and it doesnt look harmful. There are bots scanning websites these days. thats normal.

make sure your website is using SSL. In your AWS security group, just accept https traffic (port 443) only.

In regards using PHP, php is a popular language used by million of websites on the internet. As others highlighted, follow the security standards and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Did you run any security scanner tool against your web application ?

These logs looks like generated by your hosting server WAF(web application firewall)  and it seems someone tried a script/scanner against you web application, because you are not using WP but in logs script tried to find wp-config.php through LFI(path travel attack), do one simple thing, use a free or trial automatic web application scanner and check logs again, some free scanner are owasp zap, arachni scanner, paid scanner like burp-suite.

Also check following best practices for security :

- Check for any  other files which created automatically and not by you
  or framework, specially .php, and scan those files at
  "virustotal.com" to verify if actually attacker successfully uploaded a shell (virus).
- If your web-application has file upload option, please verify you
  allowing only .jpg or .png not php or other files.
- Use latest version in PHP, because a new attack now days targeting
  vulnerable PHP server, attacker pick IP range and run script against, this most happens with AWS.
- In AWS only allow 80/443 port to public IP, not all ports.
- Use latest version of framework (codeigniter).

Thanks